# NestJS Service throwing error with @InjectModel

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I have a nestJs app I'm working on and I cannot figure out why this is happening. I'm using the mongoose module to get my model prepped for the service, and I have it defined and exported from the schema file.

I've defined the model with the import for the mongoose module.

```
@Module({
    imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: 'Message', schema: MessageSchema}])],
    providers: [MessageService],
    exports: [MessageService]
})
```

and in the service I'm using `@InjectModel()` to inject the message model to the service like this:
(with `Model` being imported from `mongoose`, and `Message` being imported from the schema file.

```
constructor(
    @InjectModel('Message') private readonly messageModel: Model<Message>
  )
```

But I still have this error:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MessageService (?). Please make sure that the argument MessageModel at index [0] is available in the MessageService context.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have the `MongooseModule.forRoot` import?

Comment: Sorry, it turned out I imported the service into the dependent module, and not the module. This was not addressed in the question, and I'll update to reflect, then answer the question

Comment: Have you found the solution, Please put it here. I am struggling with the same issue for 2 days.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, What I would do is basically export MongooseModule as well in the decorator options.

```js
@Module({
    imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: 'Message', schema: MessageSchema}])],
    providers: [MessageService],
    exports: [MongooseModule,MessageService] // <-- added MongooseModule here
})
export class MessageModule {}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. I was following the official documentation which was giving me a compile error. Adding the line `exports: [MongooseModule],` to the **cats.module.ts** file solved the issue I had getting it work with MongoDB.

Comment: after 2 hours of debugging where the error from, this solved the issue for me, bless you!